# Race condition with an Angular 1 Service for an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, race-condition

Fairly new to Angular...

So If I'm using Ajax (rather than $http) in an Angular service, I want to keep a reference to a callback function. I suspect that there may be a race condition here with the `this.callback` variable.

Can another session come in and stomp on `this.callback` while the first session is still doing the Ajax call?

```
var myServer = angular.module("mymod", ["my.server"]);

myServer.service("$myservice",         

    function($server) 
    {
        var me = this;        
        this.callback = null; 

        this.saveDone = function(data)
        {
            if (me.callback) me.callback();
        }

        this.save = function(item, cb)
        {
            me.callback = cb; 

            dict = {"name" : "savePDataStory"};
            dict.item = item;        
            actions = [dict];

            $server.realAjaxCall(actions, this.saveDone, true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Each call to `save` will overwrite `this.callback` since it is shared across calls to `save`. A solution is to store the callback inside `save` itself which will be unique per invocation of the function. You can do this inline like so:

```
$server.realAjaxCall(actions, function (data) {
    cb();
}, true);
```

This preserves the behavior of the original code snippet which doesn't include `data` when `callback` is called. If you don't mind passing `data` through to `callback`, you can simplify it by using `cb` directly instead of wrapping it inside a function:

```
$server.realAjaxCall(actions, cb, true);
```